# Regular expression javascript change value of param in url

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using regex, I want to write a function that will replace a get parameter with a new value.

For example the following will replace pin with a new value. If the parameter doesn't exist, we will add it to the url.

```
  myfunc('http://localhost:8080/signup.html?first_name=Ray&username=ray%2B1%40gmail.com&bid=257&pin=1908554354&provisionalId=258&last_name=Ya&debug=true#/signupnew', 'pin', 'AAAAAAA');

// returns http://localhost:8080/signup.html?first_name=Ray&username=ray%2B1%40gmail.com&bid=257&pin=AAAAAAA&provisionalId=258&last_name=Ya&debug=true#/signupnew
```

Comment: What is your current code ? What have you done ? Where are you blocking ?

Comment: Just as an FYI, if you want this new parameter to show in the URL, you will have to either a) reload the page, as you cannot update the query string directly, or b) take advantage of the ***HTML5 History API*** which does have the ability to modify the query string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the function like this :

```
function myfunc(url, name, value) {
   return url.replace(new RegExp("(\\?|&)"+name+"=.*?($|&)"), '$1'+name+'='+value+'$2')
}
```

This suppose the name and values are yet escaped for an URL.

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/eqifey/1/edit) (open the console to see the result)